# Problem using libxml2 with VS Code under Windows (g++)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code, g++, libxml2

I'm not new to programming, but pretty new to C++. I successfully loaded some other 3rd party libraries like curl or sqlite, but I'm having a problem with libxml2 (Platform Windows; IDE VS Code; Compiler g++). I downloaded the binary from zlatkovic.com (x86_x64 if it matters).

After including one or two header files and typing a few lines I wanted to see what the result would be and I tried to compile my code. I added the libxml2-2.dll in my vs code task file under the '-g' flag of the compiler, just like I did it with the others. But this time I received the following message:

```
"path/to/src/libxml/xmlreader.h:16:10: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory"
```

Like you can see in the message, the header files are in the "libxml" directory and I also checked they exist.

I guess it's something really basic I'm missing out here, but help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you edit your `tasks.json` and your `c_cpp_properties.json` to add the include path for your compiler and for intellisense? Or are you using CMake in VSCode?

Comment: How does your VS-Code task configuration look like? Where is that library installed at your system? Do your compiler and linker flags contain the correct search paths for headers and library files?

Comment: I added them in my c_cpp_properties.json just like the others: 
"${workspaceFolder}/**",
"${workspaceFolder}/curl/**",
"${workspaceFolder}/sqlite/**",
"${workspaceFolder}/libxml/**"

Comment: In my tasks.json I also added the library just like the other:                 "${fileDirname}\\sqlite\\sqlite3.dll",
                "${fileDirname}\\curl\\libcurl.dll",
                "${fileDirname}\\libxml\\libxml2-2.dll",

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it. I needed the '-I' flag to the directory with the header files. Thanks everyone!